# Is UDP Considered to be a "Best-Effort" Service?

Tags: udp

I would like to know if UDP is considered to be a "best-effort" service?

The reason I ask is because there are no guarantees that any of the packets will reach their destination/s at all.  Therefore, could UDP be classed as "best-effort" or is there another term which is deemed the "correct" way of describing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I tend to think of it as a "Good luck!" service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really best effort, more *fire and forget*.  Although the term "best effort" is actually used IMHO it's incorrect, since in non-telecoms usage it implies at least a modicum of effort beyond default behaviour, and often somewhat more than that.

No part of the network makes any special allowances for *any* IP packet except when there's *Quality of Service* in place, and even then that's really hop-by-hop rather than end-to-end.

Comment: Best effort refers to a network where there are no special allowances for the packets.

Comment: @Alnitak, compared with TCP, UDP is best effort, because TCP provides sequencing and retransmission beyond what UDP does.

Comment: indeed, although it's the end nodes that provide that, not the intermediate ones.

Comment: @Alnitak, intermediate nodes are not supposed to provide sequencing and retransmission

Comment: @Arelius, all IP traffic is by-definition best-effort.

Comment: @Mike but as an abstraction atop of IP traffic, TCP provides more then a best-effort service.

Comment: @Arelius, you argued that "best effort" applies to a network where there are no special allowances for packets.  The point is all IP networks are best effort, and the **endpoints** are the ones that can provide some level of sequencing and retransmission.  So I'm trying to understand the point you're making in your first comment 20 hours ago

Comment: @Mike, that's true, but I was using the term network to encompass the entire network, endpoints, and protocol. Anyways, the comment only makes sense if there were no edits to the answer, as I took the wordage directly from the answer I was responding too.

Answer (score 5):

Best-effort is one way to describe UDP; however, saying it's best-effort is kindof ambiguous.

A better word for UDP packet delivery is "unreliable"...

Consider wikipedia entries... compare the use of the words "reliable" and "reliability" from wikipedia (below)...

- Quoting from *[the TCP article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)*...

> TCP provides **reliable**, ordered, and error-checked delivery of a stream of octets (bytes) between applications running on hosts communicating via an IP network.

The issue of UDP's reliability is also discussed in wikipedia articles.

- Quoting from *[the UDP article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)*...

> UDP uses a simple connectionless communication model with a minimum of protocol mechanisms. UDP provides checksums for data integrity, and port numbers for addressing different functions at the source and destination of the datagram. It has no handshaking dialogues, and thus exposes the user's program to any **unreliability** of the underlying network; there is no guarantee of delivery, ordering, or duplicate protection.

- From the UDP RFC -> [RFC 768 - User Datagram Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768)... emphasis mine...

> This protocol  provides  a procedure  for application  programs  to send messages  to other programs  with a minimum  of protocol mechanism.  The protocol is transaction oriented, and delivery and duplicate protection are **not guaranteed**.

When UDP applications need reliable packet delivery, they have to detect, retransmit, and de-duplicate dropped UDP packets on their own... an example UDP application which delivers these functions over UDP is [TIBCO](https://support.tibco.com/s/) quote streaming.

Comment: I still can't see how it's best-effort from your answer. If protections are not guaranteed and it has minimum mechanisms in it, isn't it lowest-effort then (as it does very little)? While TCP would be best-effort (as it puts a lot of effort into these guarantees)? (I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I edited and rephrased.

Answer (score 1):

UDP is generally faster than TCP as it does not have to do the overhead checking of consistency that TCP must deal with. This means that UDP is most often used in programs where transmitting every single last packet correctly is the necessary action. This doesn't mean that UDP is a "best-effort" service, it's something more along the lines of, "You need the information now, and don't care if it's all there"

This is useful in many situations where TCP would be less optimal. For example, DNS and DHCP use UDP as it is only one packet each way. It's faster that way and when the user wants to get on the internet, speed is important. It's also used in streaming situations, where one packet lost or out of order doesn't affect the flow of the stream. Like TV, no one is going to notice if one packet is lost, it's not that big of a deal.

Anyways, I'm not able to answer this as well as wikipedia would be able to. So heres the link to UDP on Wikipeda, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Comment: While this is a reasonable description of the protocols, I feel it implies a misunderstanding of the term "best-effort"

Comment: @Arelius Best effort sounds like a shoddy attempt that will not give good results. UDP gives good results, but just for certain applications of it. To me, best effort sounds bad. UDP isn't bad like it would make it sound.

Comment: Really? Neither of the words sound negative. UDP gives good results, for transmission that only requires best effort.

Comment: I don't know really. Best effort has always seemed to me to be the type of work that just gets someone shafted. Like, trying to get a flight with 1 transfer but instead getting told you have 5. Or getting cut from a team over the coaches son even though he was worse. Something like that.

Comment: Huh, that seems more like "Good enough effort" to me.

Comment: I guess it's just different connotations of the term.